# NSButton and Image Animation

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

Hello
I am writing an mac os x application that contains several nsbuttons.
Each nsbutton has its own image.
When you press the nsbutton, there is a change of image.
Is there an option to add animation when changing images on the nsbutton?

Answer (score 0):

you can subclass nsbutton and can use the button's view's layer to do animation whenever the image needs to be changed.
NSButton is also a subclass of NSView so it also will be having a proxy animator object but in that case i guess whole button might get animated and not just image that you want.
Hope it helps